# Deleting a Record in a CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am developing a basic application using WPF in C# which reads in data stored in a CSV file. I have been able to read in the data successfully in other parts of my application and display them using Data Grid in WPF. I am now looking to delete a record when the user enters a searchterm. The application will then read through the CSV file using streamreader and find where the record matches the search term entered by the user is and then delete the record.

My current code is below for the delete function:

```
private void DeleteCategory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ////take user input for animal category
            string category = inputCategoryDelete.Text;

            var lines = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\ashle\OneDrive\Documents\Object Orientated Programming\Practise\CSV Files\animalcategory.csv"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (lines[i].StartsWith(category))
                        {
                            lines.RemoveAt(i);
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

                //close the popup
                addCategoryPopup.IsOpen = false;

        }
```

I am currently finding myself stuck in the for loop as it is never able to progress onto the if and else. When looking at the values of i and the lines.count. I have found that the i is able to increase by one each time but the lines.count is always at 0. I have attempted to put some breakpoints in for some basic debugging. When I change the for loop to for(int i = 0; i <= lines.count; i++) I am able to move onto the if and else statements but receive the Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection error and cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

If anyone is able to see what I am doing wrong then that would be great. I am new here so if I have missed out anything or not explained anything properly then please ask any questions :)

Comment: *"but the lines.count is always at 0"* - Because `lines` is an empty list.  It's declared but then never used.  What information are you expecting `lines` to contain and why?

Comment: @David sorry, I was hoping the lines list would contain the records in my csv file so would actually contain some information.

Comment: You'll need to place data into the list, before the count will be non-zero

Comment: Consider using a library for reading CSV, such as [NReco.Csv](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.Csv/)

Comment: you stuck in the loop because of the `while (!reader.EndOfStream)`, the reader has not been use yet so it will never at `EndOfStream`

Comment: @ash1997: `new List<string>()` just creates a new empty list of strings.  It doesn't read from a file.  You claim that elsewhere in your project you are able to read the file to display it.  In what way does that code differ from how you are reading the file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but should work in my opinion:

```
        ////take user input for animal category
        string category = "asd"; //getting cathegory that needs to be deleted
        int columnIndex = 1; //index of the field that contains the cathegories
        char separatorChar = '\t'; //separator char is tabulator that separates the different columns

        var lines = new List<string[]>(); //csv so it has multiple columns

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"file path")) //getting the file
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                lines.Add(reader.ReadLine().Split(separatorChar)); //adding the files content line-by-line and split by the separator character
            }
        }
        //now we have the lines list that contains the csv-s lines and splitted into string entities that represents the column of a line

        foreach (var line in lines) //we iterate through the line entities
        {
            if (line[columnIndex] == category) //cathegory equals with the user inputted cathegory?
                line[columnIndex] = string.Empty; //delete column content if this is true
        }


        using (var writer= new StreamWriter(@"file path")) //write back to the file
        {
            foreach (var item in lines)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(separatorChar.ToString(), item)); //convert string[] to string (line)
            }
        }
```

One simple modification is that you only want to replace data from a specific column, so I modified the code to take care of that too and wrote a writeback too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments on your code too. This really helped me to understand where I was going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like below. (So that you build a list of file lines that do not start with your category as this saves you checking for and then deleting it from the List.)

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\ashle\OneDrive\Documents\Object Orientated Programming\Practise\CSV Files\animalcategory.csv"))
    {
        while ( reader.Peek() >=0)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if(!line.StartsWith(category))
                lines.Add(line);
        }
    }
```